# Change column order of a table in db2 luw

Tags: db2, db2-luw

I have table with below column definitions in db2 luw version 10.5. I want to change the order of columns OPTCOUNTER and COMPNAME.

Is there any way to do this apart from dropping and re-creating the table?

```
                                Data type                     Column
Column name                     schema    Data type name      Length     Scale Nulls
------------------------------- --------- ------------------- ---------- ----- ------
DATABASEVENDOR                  SYSIBM    VARCHAR                     32     0 Yes
EDITION                         SYSIBM    VARCHAR                     16     0 Yes
VERSION                         SYSIBM    SMALLINT                     2     0 Yes
RELEASE                         SYSIBM    SMALLINT                     2     0 Yes
MOD                             SYSIBM    SMALLINT                     2     0 Yes
FIXPACK                         SYSIBM    SMALLINT                     2     0 Yes
OPTCOUNTER                      SYSIBM    SMALLINT                     2     0 Yes
COMPNAME                        SYSIBM    VARCHAR                     32     0 No

  8 record(s) selected.
```

Comment: create a view with the columns in the desired order.

Answer (score 0):

First of, why do you want to change the column order? From the table layout this seems ok because you have the variable length column after a fixed length column.

Second, wouldn't simply using a `SELECT` in which you explicitly state the column names solve it...?

```
select DATABASEVENDOR, EDITION, VERSION, RELEASE, MOD, FIXPACK, COMPNAME, OPTCOUNTER
from MYTABLE
```

In case you want to really change the column order, use [ALTER TABLE](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000888.html?pos=2) and first DROP optcounter, then ADD it again.

Comment: Thanks for the update.

I want this table definitions to be in sync with another database.
In the other database table, COMPNAME name column comes first and then the column OPTCOUNTER.

Comment: Ok, in that case you can either drop the entire table and recreate it or use ALTER TABLE to drop and add the column optcounter.

Comment: @Lakshmikanth - I have to echo data_henrik here, though: column order should be irrelevant, and considered an implementation detail.  I'm not sure databases are required to **store** it in the listed order (in preference for some optimization possibilities).  And you should always explicitly list out your columns, since otherwise the column list is somewhat _undefined_; for example, when you do this rename, anybody who **didn't** list out columns is in for a big surprise (and hopefully get an error).

Answer (score 0):

From application side the column order shouldn't be relevant as you should use explicit column lists in your SQL statements.

If using something like liquibase the column order is relevant as different column order would always be considered as differences within databases.

My approach here would be (if no referential integrity/foreign key definition) on the table is given to create a table with the correct column order, load the data from the old table into the new one, drop the old one and rename the new one to the old name.